# Send a 404 error via htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

I'd like to cut off access to a subdirectory on my site but I want any access in the subdirectory to be a 404 error, not a 403 forbidden. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: redirect to a non-existent directory should do it... use a rewrite rule

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^directory/ - [L,R=404]
```

This redirects all requests for the folder "`/directory/`", they get a 404 response.

Comment: along with this 404 status, can we show the content of a 404.html page?

Comment: what about PHP and css/html, can they still access the folder?

Comment: I get 500 in log instead 404

Comment: do you have mod_rewrite turned on?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=404] 
if you want all subdirectories and files inside the folder included with the GET method only.

Comment: mod_rewrite.c have to be enabled

Answer (score 5):

I think,  410 error  better

```
RewriteRule ^directory/ - [L,R=410]
```

or my search:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=410,L]
```

[on russian wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#404)

> 404 Not Found [19] - the most common mistake when using the Internet, the main reason - an error in writing the address of a Web page. The server understood the request, but did not find the corresponding resource at the specified URL. If the server knows that there was a document at this address, then it is desirable for it to use code 410. Answer 404 can be used instead of 403 if you need to carefully hide certain resources from prying eyes. Appeared in HTTP/1.0.

Answer (score 3):

```apache
Redirect 404
```

Put this into the .htaccess file in the directory that you want off the record. The [Redirect directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) is part of mod_alias and can be used to send any status code, not just redirects.

Answer (score 2):

You could also for the time being change which page a user will see when confronted with a 403 error, but I wouldn't recommend doing this long-term.

.htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /your404pagehere.php
```